# How do I set an HTTP Request Default based on a URL rather than host, port, scheme?

Tags: jmeter

I'm just starting with JMeter and porting my Postman API.  I was wondering is there a way to have the user defined variable as

```
baseUrl=http://localhost:28082
```

And have HTTP request defaults or equivalent using that value so we don't have to break up the components?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can put the full URL into Path field of HTTP Request sampler (or HTTP Request Defaults)

[image]

but in that case it might cause malfunction of other test elements like [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager) or [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) so it's better to split it into protocol, host and port and manipulate the path.

Also HTTP Request Defaults assume "default" values which will be populate if you leave this field empty in the HTTP Request sampler so this "baseURL" won't act as a "prefix"

Answer (score 0):

I added a parser BeanShell Sampler (since I have JDK17 in my PC and Groovy is causing issues)

```java
import java.net.URI;
SampleResult.setIgnore();
var baseUri = URI.create(vars.get("baseUri"));
var httpProtocol = baseUri.getScheme();
var httpHost = baseUri.getHost();
var port = baseUri.getPort();
if (port == 0 && httpProtocol.equals("https")) {
    port = 443;
} else if (port == 0) {
    port = 80;
}
var httpPrefix = baseUri.getPath();
vars.put("httpProtocol", httpProtocol);
vars.put("httpPort", String.valueOf(port));
vars.put("httpHost", httpHost);
vars.put("httpPrefix", httpPrefix);
```

Then put the variables in.

[image]

I added support for prefix though I never really use it in my JMeter files at the moment